# Google Chrome intermittent load issue: possible to Programatically disable "Predict network actions..."?

Tags: html, google-chrome, load

I'm having a very strange problem with a site in Google Chrome:

When I click on a link (from a list view to a detail page), the page hangs and I Chrome throws up a dialogue asking me to kill the page. The page is never displayed.

*But* if I navigate directly to the page, it loads in Chrome without any problems. Both actions (clicking on a link *or* navigating to the page) work fine in Safari and Firefox.

Disabling "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" in Chrome's settings seems to fix the problem, but this is not a viable solution as I don't have any control of my user's browser settings.

**Some more detail about the situation:**

- The link is just a regular `<href>`. I'm not doing any javascript
  `click()` handling or anything else. I'm not using any 'prefetch' or 'prerender' `<link>` elements.
- The pages all validate using the W3
  html5 validator.
- The page I'm navigating to loads a lot of JS, uses [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) for rendering and loads a video file over HTTP.
- On the occasions that the page *does* load (after a very long wait),
  Chrome appears to have rendered the entire page in the background and
  loaded all external resources. If I navigate directly to the page it
  doesn't preload anything though (I'm using knockout to show a 'please
  wait' message while the external resources load).
- When I log the network requests using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), it appears that
  Chrome loads the HTML for the page instantly, but the requests for
  the external resources seem to take forever.
- If I look at the CPU usage in Activity Monitor, 'Google Chrome Renderer' uses 100% CPU when loading from the `href`, but only 30% when loading directly from the page.
- I'm using the latest version of Chrome (22.0.1229.94)

**So - my question**

Is there a way to programatically disable "Predict network actions to improve page load performance"?

Or is there some other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just going through high voted unanswered questions I came across this one, and I once got into a similar situation for entirely different reasons (chrome was preloading a **huge** file I couldn't afford to load for every user). The fairly simple solution I applied back then was to open the link through Javascript rather than a simple `href` which worked wonders. Either way, your problem might already be solved, but seeing the number of views I thought I could at least share this small insight.